# How do I read a file directory in C to get the Names of all non-folder files

Tags: c, directory, process

I am trying to read a given directory filePath and get the names of all non folder files into a array of strings. **So the issue that I need solved is how to specifically not get folder type files but also get all the other file type names and store them into the string array.** Later I plan to use threads to read these individual files as well, but I need to be able to store the files names properly. The code that I am currently using is below. It should also be noted that this code is being executed by a child process from the fork() command, but I am not sure if that is relevant to the issue anyway. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example:
In the Home/Documents there are 4 files: hello.txt something.dat folder1 something2.dat

My string array should have the values hello.txt, something.dat, and something2.dat

Note: It is okay for me not to do the files as a I go through the directory as the files themselves are not going to be changed at all content wise.

```
//char* directory is an absolute filePath to the directory
void getFilesFromDirectory(char* directory, pid_t process)
{
    int index =0;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    //Can hold only 500 valid files in the folder
    char *stringArray[500];
    if ((dir = opendir (directory)) != NULL) 
    {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
        {            
            strcpy(stringArray[index],ent->d_name);
            index++;         
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } 
    else 
    {
        /* could not open directory */
         perror ("");
    }

   //Everything Below is not related to the problem. Just what I am using it for.

    pthread_t threadArray[index];
    pthread_t senderThread;
    //thread_param_t parameterSender;
    thread_param_t paramterArray[index];

    sem_init(&empty,0,bufferSize);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    //parameterSender.listItem = listHead;
    pthread_create(&senderThread, NULL, senderFunction, NULL);
    //int threadCounter = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<index; i++)
    {
        paramterArray[i].fileLocation = strcat(directory, stringArray[i]);
        pthread_create(&threadArray[i], NULL, threadFunction, paramterArray + i);

    }
}
```

Comment: "I am not sure if that is relevant to the issue". What issue? You haven't actually asked a question or described what problems you are having that you need help with.

Comment: `char *stringArray[500]; strcpy(stringArray[index],ent->d_name);` You are copying to uninitialised pointers. You need to allocate memory for each string.

Comment: Be sure to check the value of `index` for when there are more than `500` files.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and *one* specific question. Otherwise this Q should be closed.

Comment: Do you actually need them all?  Typically, it is better to read one name and then use it, then move on to the next.  If you read all the data into memory and then iterate over the in-memory copy, you are very likely to be using stale data.

Comment: There are lots of questions here. But if its just the title question, then the answer is to study [nftw(3p)](https://www.mankier.com/3p/nftw) and get a hang of it correctly. For each item in the directory, it invokes a call back and gives [stat(2)](https://www.mankier.com/2/stat). Ignore all `S_IFDIR` but insert everything else.

Comment: The posted code fails to ignore file names `.` and `..` and anything that is NOT a normal file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine file/folder in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868994/determine-file-folder-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check `stringArray` for files without "." and set this pointer to Null. (There are files missing)

A better option is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>


int main()
{
    DIR *folder;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;

    folder = opendir(".");
    if(folder == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to read directory");
        return(1);
    }
    printf("debug\n");
    while( (entry=readdir(folder)) )
    {
        files++;
        printf("File %3d: %s :: %s\n",
                files,
                entry->d_name,
                (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)?"Directory" : "File"
              );
    }

    closedir(folder);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Filenames may not have dots, e.g. executables; and why set the pointer in `stringArray[]` to `NULL` when you could just move on to the next entry when a folder is encountered?

Comment: This is true. But do you have a better workarround? It depends what files you need. But I assumed, that this is about "normal" e.g. .txt, .md .mp3 etc. files. Besides: there are also folders with a dot at least in Linux. But it is in the name[0] position.

Comment: "Normal" files do not always have dots in the filenames; this is especially common on *nix systems. Not just executables, either. Look at the installation directory for any open source linux project and you are likely to see text files named `INSTALL`, `README`, `BUGS`, etc. The true answer will depend on the OS, but see the proposed duplicate I linked to in my comment above for an alternative